# NSE Script - Confusion with the use of self on table's function

Tags: lua

Good day, I'm trying to understand a little more  NSE scripts that are based on Lua, but there is something that  I can't understand related to syntax when using functions as elements from a table.  I'm going to show  parts of the script  nmap/scripts/broadcast-rip-discver.nse where I'm getting lost:

```
RIPv2 = {


    -- The Request class contains functions to build a RIPv2 Request
    Request = {

        -- Creates a new Request instance
        --
        -- @param command number containing the RIPv2 Command to use
        -- @return o instance of request
        -- code ommitted (give values to the table o) 
            setmetatable(o, self)
            self.__index = self
            return o
        end,

        -- Converts the whole request to a string
        __tostring = function(self)
            --- -- code ommitted  ( Override the metafunction __tostring) 
            return data
        end,

    },

    -- The Response class contains code needed to parse a RIPv2 response
    Response = {

        -- Creates a new Response instance based on raw socket data
        --
        -- @param data string containing the raw socket response
        -- @return o Response instance
        new = function(self, data)
            local o = { data = data }

            -- code ommitted (Read from data and pass values to o) 

            setmetatable(o, self)
            self.__index = self
            return o
        end,

    }

}
```

And from the "action" part of the script we have a use like this

```
 local rip = RIPv2.Request:new(RIPv2.Command.Request) 
 local response = RIPv2.Response:new(data) -- Data has been already give a value
```

I understand that is "similar" to create a new instance of the Table RIPv2 for those two lines.  As all the function are inside of a table (that is not a class because Lua only  have basic tools for make things similar but no the same to class) so the "self" argument it's mandatory for Lua have a idea to where place that.

But what I can't understand it's why try to override functions from the table RIPv2 to the table o, I mean the lines what objective has?: 
      setmetatable(o, self) )

I understand that the variable table o could have now the same functions that RIPv2  together  his own values but this part make me crazy and I can't find a straight answer at Nmap's Forum.

P.d. which would be the difference to declare RiPv2 with "local"  (Be sure that is not a Global variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As all the function are inside of a table so the "self" argument it's mandatory for Lua have a idea to where place that.

All the functions aren't *necessarily* part of the table. A metatable allows you to specify that lookups in table `a` can resolve to lookups in table `b`, and that's exactly what's being done here.

> But what I can't understand it's why try to override functions from the table RIPv2 to the table o, I mean the lines what objective has?: setmetatable(o, self) )

`o` is an *instance* of a class, it contains only the instance data. The *methods* are stored in class objects `Request` or `Response`. The metatable allows attempts to index `o` to resolve via the class object.

[See the *Programming in Lua* chapter on classes.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses)